# Library for photo-booth style effects

Tags: image, image-processing, photos

Are there any good tools or libraries that do image effects similar to Photo Booth on OS X? It doesn't have to be live, just applying the effect to an image would be enough. As a bonus: python bindings preferred.

Comment: What platforms are you targeting for this? OS X?

Comment: Windows, or possibly Android. (I know, big difference.)

Answer (score 0):

[What about image magick ?](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

It does a lot of effect, is Python compliant and can do way more than what you aim at.
You can use it in console or through the api.

[Example of effects (sepia included)](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)

With it, you can distort, blur, watermark,  . . . whatever you want :)

It supports [a lot of languages](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php), and there is even a port to android on [github](https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick)